# API DistanceMatrix - Obter informação de tempo de viagem

Tags: php, javascript, api, google-maps

Pesquisei bastante e acabei descobrindo que para descobrir a duração de viagem entre dois pontos considerando o trânsito é necessário pagar. Beleza!
Então como obtenho a duração sem considerar o transito?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando chamo a **API** com meus parâmetros ([LINK AQUI](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=06515-005&destinations=06090-010&mode=driving&language=pt-br&sensor=false)), a duração vem sempre errada!

Obrigado desde já!

Answer (score 0):

"Então como obtenho a duração sem considerar o transito?"
Sua resposta está na sua pergunta. No retorno da Api do google maps, ele retorna os mesmos 31 min mostrados na sua imagem.

"duration" : {
  "text" : "31 minutos",
  "value" : 1858
 }